# Page is still redirecting after changing Windows hosts file

Tags: windows, apache, hosts

On my Windows hosts file I added this line:

```
127.0.0.1 testing.whatsapp.com
```

After that I cleared DNS entries with the command `ipconfig /flushdns` and then I tried to access `http://testing.whatsapp.com` on my Chrome. It ALWAYS gets redirected to `https://testing.whatsapp.com` (SSL) version. I have no extensions installed on my Chrome which would cause this. So I tried the same on Firefox and on Edge - same exactly problem.

My Apache has no redirects configured and the proof of that is when I change the hosts file and replace the `whatsapp.com` domain with anything else, it always works, I mean: the redirect never happens. Any domain I tried, worked fine, no redirects - except `whatsapp.com` subdomains.

So what is the weird thing that WhatsApp domain is doing that is causing all my browser to always redirect all traffic to HTTPS even for the IPs that I listed on hosts file?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security or other kind of pinning.

Comment: @Anders I know dozens of HTTP headers and I was not aware of this header you mentioned. It was the root of my problem. If you want to post your comment as an answer, I will be glad to accept it right away.